# SyncKnowledge object not being passed to WCF service

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I am trying to sync a SQLCE database with SQL database using WCF. I have a proxy which inherits from KnowledgeSyncProvider. I override the below method (among others)

```
public override ChangeBatch GetChangeBatch(uint batchSize, SyncKnowledge destinationKnowledge, out object changeDataRetriever)
{ 

GetChangesParameters changesWrapper = proxy.GetChanges(batchSize, destinationKnowledge);

...

}
```

When the `GetChangesParameters changesWrapper = proxy.GetChanges(batchSize, destinationKnowledge);` code is executed, I get the following error

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {EC413D66-6221-4EBB-AC55-4900FB321011} failed due to the following error: 80040154.
```

Stack trace:

```
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at WCF_Sync_Common.IRelationalSyncContract.GetChanges(UInt32 batchSize, SyncKnowledge destinationKnowledge)
   at ConsoleApplication10.RelationalProviderProxy.GetChangeBatch(UInt32 batchSize, SyncKnowledge destinationKnowledge, Object& changeDataRetriever) in C:\Users\amitesh.AKL\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication10\RelationalProviderProxy.cs:line 81
   at Microsoft.Synchronization.KnowledgeProviderProxy.GetChangeBatch(UInt32 dwBatchSize, ISyncKnowledge pSyncKnowledge, ISyncChangeBatch& ppChangeBatch, Object& ppUnkDataRetriever)
```

Seems like the error has something to do with the SyncKnowledge object when passing it over the wire. I tried to call the proxy method without the SyncKnowledge object and was able to call the method. But as soon as I include the object I get the above error. Can anybody explain to point me in the right direction on what I am missing

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue by creating a WCF Service Application project and moving all the WCF code into that project. My initial WCF project was just a normal console application